# WordPress Plugin Database per User

Tags: database, wordpress

I am trying to develop a store locator script.  May exist for WordPress however, after they are installed, no matter who logs into WordPress, each user is adding/deleting entries inside that one database of addresses.

I would like to have it so that each user belongs to a group/company.  When they login to WordPress, they can only see their entries in the database.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the stores as [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) and do not give your regular users the capability [`edit_others_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_others_posts).

WordPress will then not show stores from other users, you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea.  Is there a way via capabilities to only list the posts from each user also?

Comment: Looks like it was cached.  It works perfect now, thanks a bunch.